# Having issues with Binary Tree node counting

Tags: c++, binary-tree

When calling Node Counting function in public I get incompatible declaration and in private my returns do not match the function and I cannot call in the test driver.

Float, int, void, bool(stupid I know).

CPP

```
void BinaryTree::count(TreeNode* root) {
if(root == NULL)
    return 0;
else 
    if(root->left == NULL && root->right == NULL)
        return 1;
    else
        return count(root->left) + count(root->right) + 1;    
}
```

Header (I think I need to make this public so I can call in the test driver but I was only able to declare in the CPP from Private.)

```
void count(TreeNode *);
```

Driver

```
cout << "Total Number of Nodes " << endl;
tree.count();
cout << endl;
```

In the Driver test CPP tree.count is inaccessible which is understandable because its being called from private, but as a public call the declaration is incompatible.

Comment: `BinaryTree::count` requests a `TreeNode*` as argument but `tree.count();` as no argument. If _TreeNode_ is internal to BinaryTree you need a public operation without arg and a private operation with the arg called by the public version

Comment: `void BinaryTree::count(TreeNode* root) {
if(root == NULL)
    return 0;` - is *obviously* wrong. Your function returns `void` (nothing) but you try to return a value (an integer). May I suggest reading [a good book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) (or two).? There are some basics you have not yet grasped.

Comment: @bruno  Im pretty new to classes. I have changed it into an int function and everything seems to be right except the test driver. How would I go about making tree.count into an argument?

Comment: @TylerKanz please [edit] your question and show how the `BinaryTree` class is defined. It appears that `BinaryTree::count` is probably `private` and so can't be directly called outside the class, but that's only guesswork.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> void BinaryTree::count(TreeNode* root) {
>   if(root == NULL)
>    return 0;
>   else 
>    if(root->left == NULL && root->right == NULL)
>        return 1;
>    else
>        return count(root->left) + count(root->right) + 1;    
> }
> ```

that operation return an *int* (at least a number) , it must have a signature returning a number, for instance

```
int BinaryTree::count(TreeNode* root)
```

your definition is also complicated for nothing, can be

```
 int BinaryTree::count(TreeNode* root) {
   return (root == NULL)
     ? 0
     : count(root->left) + count(root->right) + 1;    
 }
```

and because it does not modify the instance make it const

```
 int BinaryTree::count(TreeNode* root) const {
   return (root == NULL)
     ? 0
     : count(root->left) + count(root->right) + 1;    
 }
```

Having

> tree.count();

without arg and visibly writing the count you need an other operation like

```
void BinaryTree::count() const {
  cout << count(..the tree node..);
}
```

that operation must be public, probably the previous one is private

Anyway it is better to not write the count but to return it, letting the caller doing what it wants with.

So finally something like :

```
// I use a _struct because fields accessible by BinaryTree
// but  may be a class and BinaryTree is a friend class etc
struct TreeNode {
  // ...
  TreeNode * left;
  TreeNode * right;
  // ...
};

class BinaryTree {
  public:
    // ...
    int count() const { return count(tree); }
    // ...
  private:
    // ...
    int count(TreeNode *) const;
    // ...
    TreeNode * tree;
    // ...
};

int BinaryTree::count(TreeNode* root) const {
   return (root == NULL)
     ? 0
     : count(root->left) + count(root->right) + 1;    
 }
```

and somewhere `cout << "Total Number of Nodes " << tree.count() << endl;`

Comment: Ah got it! Thank you!

Comment: @TylerKanz ok, happy coding

Comment: @bruno I didn't downwote, but you should seriosly consider to stop answering _off-topic_ questions. These won't have any benefit for future research. I've been watching you doing this frequently in the [tag:c++] tag realm. Rather use your powers to sort out for good questions, and apply your powers to comment, down voting and close voting. Even better search for possible dupes, and flag as such.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I know we do not agree all the time, I probably already said you I come here to **help** rather than to *kick ass* (I speak about the OP, not about you of course ^^). For me the question wasn't not *off-topic*, we do not put the level of *off-topicness* at the same level :-)

Comment: @bruno _"I come here to help"_ Well you should notice that Stack Overflow isn't meant as a personal help desk.

Comment: @TylerKanz No, it wasn't  a good question. You've been missing to post a [mcve] research, debugging and a number of other things before asking.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Im sorry I offended you and broke the rules. Like Ive said Im newish to this.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I am not supporting anybody. The OP lacks a minimal complete solution. However, downvoter of this answer could just show up and warn the bruno  to don't do or wait for the MCVC. Anonymous DV's I found really bad. On the other hand, the answer isn't at all bad.

Comment: @UsingCpp thank you. Often the quality of a question is grey, but is that grey dark or light ? We do not have all the same view. Anyway to reassure πάνταῥεῖ I also vote to close questions ;-)